# How to check C libraries installed without root access?

Tags: c, linux, gcc, archlinux, c-libraries

I am working on a school project in a limited environment (archlinux) where I don't have root access. The subject says that I am allowed to use all libraries that are already installed. I am coding in C using gcc.

How to get a list of all those libraries ?

Answer (score 3):

For those libraries managed by the [`pkg-config`](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/pkg-config/) utility, the following command will show all installed libraries:

```
pkg-config --list-all | less
```

However, not all libraries are so managed so you may be forced to go through the `/usr/lib` and `/usr/local/lib` directories.

Answer (score 2):

As noted, not all libraries necessarily use `pkg-config`.  Given that this is ArchLinux, as a fallback you could learn to use the package manager, to list the installed packages.  That is called [`pacman`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Pacman).

Anything that is *installed* as such on ArchLinux would be part of a *package*.

The [query options](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Pacman#Querying_package_databases) can show you all of the files installed for given packages:

- To list all files for a given package, use `pacman -Ql`*package_name*
- To list all packages, use `pacman -Q`

(scripting that, to list all ".so" files which are installed, by package name would be an interesting exercise).

Comment: Life can be made much easier with a few helpful aliases in `.bashrc` as well. (e.g. `alias pmq='pacman -Q'`; `alias pmql='pacman -Ql'`, etc...)

Comment: Aliases are helpful to some people; I write far more scripts than aliases due to the way my environment works.

Answer (score 1):

```
ls /lib /usr/lib /usr/local/lib
```